# How do I make the form submit successful and also redirect to another part of the website?

Tags: php, html

```
{
        $output = json_encode(array('status'=>'false', 'message' => '<strong>Error!</strong> Se require informacion corecta.'));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('status'=>'true', 'message' => '<strong>Gracias!</strong> En breve recibiras una oferta. '));
        die($output);
```

How can I make the form redirect to another page instead of displaying a thank you message? The form is at the beginning of the website. So customers can enter their information but when the form submits successfully, it should take them to another page making it seem like they got access to enter the website.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please [format your question](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) to make it easier to read.

Comment: Use redirect method in success condition

Answer (score 0):

You could replace

```
$output = json_encode(array('status'=>'true', 'message' => '<strong>Gracias!</strong> En breve recibiras una oferta. '));
    die($output);
```

with

```
header("Location: foo.html");
```

This will redirect the user to foo.html.

Comment: … only if this is not a background request (AJAX), what the fact that it was returning JSON until now rather suggests though. In that case, this will not redirect the front end, but only the AJAX request itself.

Comment: ahh I didn't notice that. Oops.